# errors.full_messages format in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Got a small question in here.

My flash notice/alerts is inside `[" "]`

[image]

In my controller, I have to show the errors if the form isn't saved.

```
format.html { redirect_to  new_project_procurement_management_plan_path, alert:"#{@project_procurement_management_plan.errors.full_messages}"}
```

Here's how i put flash into views:

**_alert.html.erb**:

```
<% [:notice, :error, :alert].each do |level| %>
  <% unless flash[level].blank? %>
    <div class="alert alert-<%= flash_class(level) %>" id="flash">
      <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert" href="#">×</a>
      <%= content_tag :p, flash[level] %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

And in my helper file:

```
#Flash Message

    def flash_class(level)
        case level
        when :notice then "success"
        when :error then "error"
        when :alert then "error"
    end
  end
```

Now how can I remove my error display inside `[" "]`

Anyone knows where to configure it? Thanks.

**EDIT**

This is the validation message in my model:

```
def equality
    self.items.each do |item|
      errors.add(:base, "#{item.description.capitalize}: Quantity must be equal to the breakdown of quantity!") if item.months != item.qty
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 49):

`errors.full_messages` returns an array of all the error messages which is why you see the brackets and quotes.  You can use `.to_sentence` to turn that array into a readable sentence.

`@project_procurement_management_plan.errors.full_messages.to_sentence`

Comment: thank you. When I use this to populate an alert message using javascript it uses funny symbols: "Building can&#39;t be blank" ---> any idea how i can get rid of the "&#39"  any pointers would be much appreciated

Comment: Looks like the javascript is trying to sanitize your string for you, you probably just need to use something like `unescape()` or similar to get the formatting back to normal

Comment: To add to your answer, I've found that inspecting what's being returned is helpful. I would have either used a debug statement in the controller to view what `@project_procurement_management_plan.errors.full_messages` returns or the same in a `Rails` console.